# Memoization in Javascript from Crockford's book

Tags: javascript, memoization

**Example 1.**

```
var fibonacci = function () {
  var memo = [0, 1];
  var fib = function (n) {
    var result = memo[n];

    if (typeof result !== 'number') {
      result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
      memo[n] = result;
    }

    return result;
  };

  return fib;
}();
```

**Example 2.**

```
var memoizer = function (memo, fundamental) {
  var shell = function (n) {
    var result = memo[n];

    if (typeof result !== 'number') {
      result = fundamental(shell, n);
      memo[n] = result;
    }

    return result;
  };

  return shell;
};

var fibonacci = memoizer([0, 1], function (shell, n) {
  return shell(n - 1) + shell(n - 2);
});
```

Above are 2 code snippets from Crockford's book to demonstrate the concept of memoization.

Question 1. How do I invoke function fibonacci from any of 2 examples? By usual way **fibonacci (5)**?

Question 2. As I can see, argument "n" is not defined anywhere when calling ***var fib = function (n) {*** or ***var shell = function (n) {***.
In the first example of fibonacci function I'd expect "n" to be defined right after the 2nd line *var memo = [0, 1];*, and I'd expect "n" to be defined as follows: **n = arguments[0];**.
However since this doesn't seem to be the case, so I have to ask: how is "n" determined when fibonacci is invoked?

Thanks.

[Page from Crockford's books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJc02.jpg)

Comment: n is a parameter to the anonymous function assigned to the variable `recur`, so it is indeed defined. You need to put the code necessary to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*, not in a picture in a link. Doesn't matter if somebody else understands you. This question does not meet the site standards and needs to be appropriately edited or it will be closed.

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes to edit it

Comment: By the way, I wonder why the image attachment option is available if noone can use it due to "site standards"?

Comment: It's for things that aren't code. For instance, if you're working on a website or a Java swing app or a GTK app or whatever and you have visual problems developing it then you can embed a screenshot. But don't use it for code or other textual data like stacktraces. I have removed my vote to close your question, thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Question 1: How do I call each one?

The first example, note the `}()` at the end. This is invoking the function, which in turn gives the `fib` function back. So `fibonacci()` in the first example is really `fib()` with it's own internal references (e.g. `memo` and `fib`), `memo` only being accessible by `fib` but lasting as a reference as long as a reference to `fib` exists (the variable holding `fibonacci`'s return).

The second example is similar, except it's substituting a memoizer that accepts an array of items and returns `shell`, which has access to the array it was passed.

#### Question 2: What is `n` as an argument doing?

Since you're really calling a reference to an internally created but externally available `fib()` and `shell()` when you call either `fibonacci` function, you're passing in a new number, which then has it's fibonacci sequence "memoized" by storing it in the internally available `memo` given at the beginning.

---

The point is that memoization is like a hash store where computations already known (since they were previously performed and "memoized") are accessible (preventing re-computation), and using Javascript's closure construct allows you to use internally-scoped variables to manage that access.

Comment: Hi, Jared. From your answer it is still unclear, how do I call both functions to get the number for, lets say, fibonacci (100) or fibonacci (200).  Since "n" is undefined while the hash for storing the values is obviously limited, there gotta be some way to stop the calcs at some point..

Comment: `n` is an argument that is the `100` and `200` you're referencing. Because `fibonacci` is actually a reference to another function defined elsewhere, the function defined in the first instance is merely what gives you the actual function you'll use back. https://jsfiddle.net/Lsxbjymw/

Comment: Try: `let foo = (a) => (b) => console.log(a, b)` `let bar = foo(1)` `bar(2)` Gives: `1 2`

Comment: Got you. Thanks.